# Recognizing text in a String Array

Tags: java, string

I am doing a project for school right now, a mini text editor. One of the basic functions is letting the user insert text, obviously. The point if for us to control input, use loops, stings and arrays.

```
do{
    System.out.println("Insira o seu texto (duplo ENTER volta ao Menu):");
    linhas [nLinhas] = input.nextLine();
}
while (!Arrays.asList(linhas).contains(""));
```

I'm asking the user to enter text, and when they do a double ENTER, they'll be back to the Menu. However, this isn't happening... I've added the cointains from a search I did online, but I can't use it, otherwise I'm going to be penalized...

I have to do this with a do-while, so how do I set up the while? I have tried this using a split, since the objective is to make the text input stop whenever a line with "" (nothing) is inserted, but it didn't work...

Any help would be awesome!

UPDATE:

```
switch (escolhaMenu){
    case 'i':
    case 'I':
        System.out.println("\nEscolheu a opção: \"Inserir linhas no fim (termine com uma linha vazia)\"\n");

        do{
            System.out.println("Insira o seu texto (duplo ENTER volta ao Menu):");
            linhas [nLinhas] = input.nextLine();
        }
        while (!Arrays.asList(linhas).contains(""));

        break;
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `!` in the `while`. You want to continue as long as the array DOESN'T contain an empty `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be

```
while (!Arrays.asList(linhas).contains(""));
```

?

As in, you want to check that the Array doesn't contain an empty string?

Also, I see your note about not being able to use "contains" . . . Try this:

```
boolean done = false;
do {
    do stuff
    String input = input.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("") {
        done = true;
    } 
} while (!done) ;
```

Comment: You are right, but even then this doesn't work. I have this inside of a switch, for recognizing input for a menu, and this runs but never lets the user input text...? It skips the input and goes back to the case of the switch, which has a break and then we are back at the Menu...

Comment: Ah.. Then it would be helpful to see the larger switch statement.

Comment: Do you have to break at the end of that case statement?  As in, are you returning to the function that called the function containing the switch statement?

Comment: Yes, I have, because before the switch is inside a do while, which has a Menu. Everyhting is working as expected in the Menu, but not here... :/

Comment: Is there any chance that your String[] is at any point being set to include empty strings?  If you've just initialized it, it should just contain null. 

Also, using "break" always makes me nervous.  Is there a way to work around that (another boolean condition to close the larger do-while loop)?

Comment: It has just been initialized, yes. It has nothing, but I want the input to put information on it, for the next line after the total number of lines already inserted, but I am completely clueless how to make this work... :/

Comment: Can we see the wider context of the code?  With "linhas [nLinhas] = input.nextLine();" don't you need to increment nLinhas in the do statement so that the next line of text is entered into the next spot in the String array?  If not, what is in the other spots of that array?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as question did change...

If you read into array... how large is it? Do you need second condition to not run over the array length?

Some comments in your code:

```
    do{
        System.out.println("Insira o seu texto (duplo ENTER volta ao Menu):");
        // Array index for nLinhas is never increased?
        // Maybe linhas[++nLinhas] = input.nextLine(); 
        linhas [nLinhas] = input.nextLine();
    }
    //Why check whole array? Wouldn't it be enough to
    //while("".equals(linhas[nLinhas])) 
    while (!Arrays.asList(linhas).contains(""));
```

Comment: Yes, I was :) I'm still not sure how to tackle this thugh... :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are putting the line into an array and then checking the entire array for "".  You should probably just be checking for what is in line you just read.  Why would it matter what came before?

Comment: The teacher won't mind, and I can't even get this to work, but that is something to check in the future for sure.

Comment: Beginning statements: int maxSIze=100;
  String [] lines = new String[maxSize];
  int [] nWords = new int[maxSize];
  int [] nChars = new int[maxSize];
  boolean [] erased = new boolean[maxSize];
  int nLines=0;             How would I have to set up the input.nextLine() so that if I already have 4 lines entered, it starts writing in the 5th?